# How do Lambda expressions infer types in Java?

Tags: java

I am currently trying to understand how Java infers the type of lambda expressions. I can illustrate with an example:

Writing:

```
producer.send(record, new Callback() {
                public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception exception) {
                    if (exception == null) {
                        logger.info("Received new metadata"
                        );
                    } else {
                        logger.error("Error while producing " + exception);
```

My IDE suggested that can be re-written to:

```
producer.send(record, (metadata, exception) -> {
    if (exception == null) {
        logger.info("Received new metadata"
        );
    } else {
        logger.error("Error while producing " + exception);
    }
```

Which made me think: How does the compiler guess the types for metadata and exception?

Reading through some articles like [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-generalized-target-type-inference#:%7E:text=Java%208%20also%20introduced%20Lambda,on%20where%20the%20expression%20appears.), I found that:

> Java 8 also introduced Lambda Expressions. Lambda Expressions do not
> have an explicit type.  Their type is inferred by looking at the
> target type of the context or situation. The Target-Type of an
> expression is the data type that the Java Compiler expects depending
> on where the expression appears.

I am not sure what is meant here by "context or situation". I am looking for a better technical explanation of how the compiler infers types. And when would I need to explicitly tag types.

Comment: To get the full picture you will have to look it up in the JLS.

Comment: A lambda can only exist in a context. The context is typically *"the left side"* to the lambda, like `Runnable foo = ` in `Runnable foo = () -> System.out.println("hello");`. Or, in your case, what the method `send` expects. In any case, a lambda is always subject to some interface. You can only use a lambda in a context where an interface is expected. The lambda will then basically create some kind of *anonymous* instance of this interface. Hence the types are determined by the expected interface. (the interface must be *functional*, so only contain one to-be-implemented method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`producer.send` is a method that accepts a record and a `Callback`, and `Callback` has exactly one abstract method, which accepts a `RecordMetadata` and an `Exception`.  Therefore, if the compiler sees a lambda as the second argument to `producer.send`, it must be implementing the method `Callback.onCompletion`, and it must have two arguments, with the first a `RecordMetadata` and the second an `Exception`.

The point being: it's inferred from the type of the method that you're passing the lambda *to*.

Comment: *"it's inferred from the type of the method that you're passing the lambda to"* perfect answer

Answer (score 1):

Adding a point to [Louis Wasserman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62920934/4405757).

The same lambda expression can be applied to different target types.

```
private static void predicate(Predicate<String> predicate) {
    predicate.test("abcd");
}

private static void function(Function<String, Boolean> function) {
    function.apply("abcd");
}


predicate(s -> s.length() > 5);
function(s -> s.length() > 5);
```

The lambda expression `s -> s.length() > 5` can both be a Predicate and a Function based on the context.

Considering method references,

```
private static void consumer(Consumer<String> consumer) {
    consumer.accept("abcd");
}

private static void function2(Function<String, Integer> function) {
    function.apply("abcd");
}
 
consumer(String::length);
function2(String::length);
```

You might be surprised to find that we can use `String::length` as a Consumer. Think of it as ignoring the return type. But expanding the method reference won't work

```
consumer(s -> {
    return s.length();
});
```